# Can't access RabbitMQ Management plugin

Tags: apache, rabbitmq, ubuntu-12.04

I am attempting to access the RabbitMQ Management plugin on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. I have a reverse proxy setup to route port 15627 to "/messages", and I've verified with Rackspace that port 15627 is open. However when I navigate to mydomain.com/messages, all I see is a blank page - no login page at all. The browser tab correctly displays "RabbitMQ Management", and the RabbitMQ service is running on the server. I am using RabbitMQ version 3.4.2.

My reverse proxy:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
ProxyPass         /messages  http://localhost:15672/
ProxyPassReverse  /messages  http://localhost:15672/
```

Here is the plugin list for RabbitMQ:

```
[e*] amqp_client               3.4.2
[e*] mochiweb                  2.7.0-rmq3.4.2-git680dba8
[E*] rabbitmq_management       3.4.2
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent 3.4.2
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch     3.4.2
[e*] webmachine                1.10.3-rmq3.4.2-gite9359c7
```

Has anyone had problems setting up rabbitmq on a proxy? I appreciate any help you can offer, thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I forgot to mention that if I navigate to my-server-ip-address:15672 I can access the RabbitMQ Management plugin, so I know that it is available on port 15672.

**EDIT 2**

Updated the proxy information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FML: all I had to do was add an extra "/" to my proxies:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
ProxyPass         /messages/  http://localhost:15672/
ProxyPassReverse  /messages/  http://localhost:15672/
```